# iOS Swift: Getting repeated value while updating 2D Array in custom UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a 2D Array which I want to populate in UITableView Custom Cell in a specific pattern.

//Retrieved from Parse backend

```
var myArray = [["Name1", "Age1"],["Name2", "Age2"],["Name3", "Age3"]]
```

//What I need is:

```
nameArray = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
ageArray = ["Age1", "Age2", "Age3]
```

So that I can use indexPath to fill the Name data in the custom UITableView cell For Ex: nameArray[indexPath.row]

I tried using the for in loop,

```
var nameArray = NSMutableArray()
var ageArray = NSMutableArray()

//Inside CellForRowAtIndexPath
for data in myArray {
   self.nameArray.addObject(data[0])
   self.ageArray.addObject(data[1])
}

   cell.nameLabel.text = "\(nameArray[indexPath.row])"
   cell.ageLabel.text = "\(ageArray[indexPath.row])"
```

But I am getting repetitive name and age label filled with Name1 and Age1 in both the cell. Does anyone know whats wrong in this?

Is there a better way to reload this data as needed?

// UPDATED FULL WORKING CODE Thanks to @l00phole who helped me solve the problem

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var data = [[String]]()
var cost = Double()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   uploadData()
}

func uploadData() {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Booking")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("X0aRnKMAM2") {
        (orders: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && orders != nil {
            self.data = (orders?.objectForKey("orderDetails"))! as! [[String]]
            //[["Vicky","21"],["Luke", "18"],["7253.58"]]
            //*****Removing the last element as it is not needed in the tableView data
            let count = self.data.count - 1
            let c = self.data.removeAtIndex(count)
            cost = Double(c[0])!
            //******
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
        self.reloadTableData()
    }
}

func reloadTableData()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return data.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:NewTableViewCell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.nameLabel.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][0])"
    cell.ageLabel.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][1])"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How are you fetching the data? You are not calling a fetch block inside cell for row at index path, are you?

Comment: Did you clear your `nameArray` and `ageArray` before loop and add new object to these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding to the `nameArray` and `ageArray` every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called and you are not clearing them first.  This seems inefficient and you should only populate those arrays when the input data changes, not when generating the cells.

I don't even think you need those arrays, as you could just do:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][0])"
cell.ageLabel.text = "\(data[indexPath.row][1])"
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more with example the inefficient part? I am confused when to reload cell as whenever I have large data, I always get weird behaviour with cell uploading with data. How can I get I insert the cells one after the other using animation when loading the cell with data?

Comment: @VickyArora OK, that sounds like a different question that requires a fair amount of information from you in order to answer correctly.  Therefore start a new question, after fixing your current issue.  The point about it being inefficient is that you are repeating something that will have no effect.  The name/age won't change all the time the input data doesn't change, therefore you need to do it only when it does change.  This can have a performance impact and is just plain wrong.

Comment: @VickyArora A note about the edit you've just attempted.  1. I cannot approve it with my low-rep.  2. You state in your question the input data is held in `myArray`, not `data`, so it won't make a lot of sense.  3.  It's not that important; the important thing is that you get the idea; you don't need the exact code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, no problem. But I want to make sure that if I click the answer as correct, the code should run when you link with the question asked. That way even an early beginner will understand. Anyways, SO is not for individuals, it for sharing with the community. Having the right information helps everyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create separate array for name and age, you can use the existing `myArray` as below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:NewTableViewCell = self.tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    let dataArray = myArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = "\(dataArray[0])"
    cell.ageLabel.text = "\(dataArray[1])"
    return cell
  } 
}
```